# Laurent series of $\frac {sin(z)}{z^2(z-\pi)}$

Tags: power-series, laurent-series

I have to find the Laurent series, around $z=0$ of $$\frac {sin(z)}{z^2(z-\pi)}$$

when $|z|>\pi$.

I've already calculated the series separately, but I'm having trouble putting the whole thing together. This is what I've done so far:

$$sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}$$

$$\frac{sin(z)}{z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n-1}$$

$$\frac{1}{z-\pi}=\frac{1}{z(1-\frac {\pi}{z})}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac {\pi}{z})^n$$

Now, I would normally do the Cauchy product, but in this case the result does not look at all like a power series. I've also tried fraction descomposition, and it the result is pretty much the same. Any ideas?

PD: Please, if somebody have any criticism, tell me. I apologize for the possible spelling mistakes. I'm not an English speaker, and sometimes the language gets a bit messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy product is fine, but it's not the Cauchy product of power series (since the series you got for $\frac{1}{z-\pi}$ is not a power series) but the Cauchy product of Laurent series. If $$f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k z^k,\qquad g(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty b_k z^k$$ in some annulus $r < \lvert z\rvert < R$, then $$f(z)g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k b_{n-k}\right)z^n$$

in at least that annulus. I don't think you get a nice short closed form for the coefficients here, but that is the normal case, only sometimes you get nice formulae for the coefficients.

Comment: So the Cauchy product formula is almost the same that in the power series? I couldn't find that anywhere! Thank you so, so much!

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that the sum extends (in general) from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ instead of from $0$ to $n$. Here, one of the two series has nonzero coefficients only for $k \geqslant -1$, and the other only for $k \leqslant -1$, so the sum is actually only infinite in one direction.

Comment: Thank you! If you could tell me where can I find this formula, some book or website, it'd be great. I could't find it anywhere.

Comment: To my surprise, that formula seems indeed rarely mentioned. The only place I found it in my books was exercise 2.b) in section $VI.1$ of the German book Funktionentheorie by Wolfgang Fischer and Ingo Lieb. There must be other occurrences, but neither Ahlfors nor Rudin seem to mention it.