# Summations from negative to positive infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

What does the series
$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k$ mean as appose to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$

Where $a_n$ is a complex sequence.

And how can one take the product of two such series (in a way similar to the cauchy product), for example the product of two
complex valued fourier series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k$ is simply a shorthand for the sum of the two series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}a_{k}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}$. For Laurent series, these are respectively called the 'regular' and 'principal' parts. This should explain how your second series differs: it is missing the negative indices. In essence, we are summing over all integers but, of course, we can't start a summation at $\infty$ so we start at some finite $k$. The $\infty$'s are shorthands for limits, not real indices.

For more information, see [Encyclopedia of Math: Laurent Series](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Laurent_series).

Regarding your second question about taking the Cauchy product of two series from $k=-\infty$, it's not very dissimilar from the form using power series; the only difference is in the indices.

For more information, see [Math Stackexchange: Laurent series of...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932704/laurent-series-of-frac-sinzz2z-pi)

Comment: When is shift k -> -k than  $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}a_{k}= \sum_{k=\infty}^{1}a_{-k}$, why do i have to change the limits, empty could be also an interpretation of this? ( i know thats not the right way but i dont get how to proof the rule behind this)

Comment: How do we prove $\sum_{k = -\infty}^{-1} a_k = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_{-k}$, i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = -n}^{-1} a_k = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n a_{-k}$? In general, order of summation for infinite series matters, right? Or is this just a definition?

Also, is this definition of $\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} a_k$ equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = -n}^n a_k$? If not, when are they equal?